# Modify html from woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation

I'm using woodmart theme, woocommerce and i can't find a way to translate these two elements "Wishlist" and "Logout" without using plugins
Usually when we change the website's language woocomerce does as well, well actually it did, but these two are still the same.
Now i'm just trying to find where their Html is and just change it but i couldn't find it[image: ScreenShot]

i inspected the elements, copied their classes, used vsCode to search for those classes but no results were found except for this class " woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link " but it only found css

Comment: Try to use the [`gettext`filter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+gettext)

Comment: Thank you it worked , here is the code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i fixed the problem Using 'gettext' :

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'rename_logout_wishlist_text', 10, 3 );
function rename_logout_wishlist_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) 
{
if ( $text === 'Logout' ) {
    $translated_text = 'Déconnexion';
}
if ( $text === 'Wishlist' ) {
    $translated_text = 'Liste de souhaits';
}
return $translated_text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'rename_logout' );
function rename_logout( $menu_links ){
    
    $menu_links[ 'customer-logout' ] = 'Get out here!';

    return $menu_links;
}
```

This will change "Logout" to "Get out here!"

Comment: It didn't work but thank you